# Help with correct usage of "who/whom" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, pronouns

in spoken language, which sentence is correct:

1. we shall celebrate the birthday of who, Mary's?
2. we shall celebrate the birthday of whom, Mary's?

Comment: What kind of research you did previously? Any grammar guide? This looks more of a ELL question than ELU

Comment: When teaching, I'd have marked both of these wrong. 'Whose birthday are we celebrating ... Mary's?' sounds like natural English. // Admittedly, "We shall celebrate the birthday of who/whom? ... Mary?" are not ungrammatical, but they're so unidiomatic that they're better avoided.

Comment: @Juliana thanks for the suggestion with migration. I'm pretty new to the community, hence the mistake!